# How to run already developed ASP.NET Core app on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core

What is the easiest way to run my existing ASP.NET Core application on Ubuntu? I have found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction but I am stuck on this: [image]

I have published the application and copied it to my Ubuntu, but I have no idea how can I "run the app". Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Scroll down in that doc file, it tell you how to start it [later on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction#monitoring-our-application)...

Comment: But it says that is should work now

Comment: Have you created a service definition and started it?

Comment: have you installed [the .NET Core runtime for Ubuntu yet](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu)?

Comment: Yes I have installed .NET Core on Ubuntu, I just don't know how to run the already published application

Comment: Try `dotnet path/to/your/application.dll`

Comment: what does the browser say when you navigate to `http://address:port`, where "address" is the host name and port is probably 80?

Comment: When I use dotnet application.dll it shows me an exception about the database so it can be it! So I run already published app with dotnet application.dll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really as simple as executing:

```
dotnet path/to/your/application.dll
```

However, for a website you really want to manage that with some sort of init system. The doc file you link to tells you how to start your application using [Systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

1. Create a service definition file e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service`
2. Edit the file to look like this, replacing the relevant parts where necessary:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Example .NET Web API Application running on Ubuntu

   [Service]
   WorkingDirectory=/var/path/to/your/app
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/path/to/your/app/hellomvc.dll
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=10  # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
   SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
   User=www-data
   Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. Enable the service like this:

   ```
   systemctl enable myapp.service
   ```
4. Start the service:

   ```
   systemctl start myapp.service
   ```
5. Check if your service is running:

   ```
   systemctl status myapp.service
   ```

If you have another init system, the instructions will of course be quite different.

**Note:** This only starts the app running on your machine. If you intend to serve it to the public, then it is highly recommended that you use a proxy such as Nginx as Microsoft has not yet certified Kestrel as an edge server.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and when it works I will mark this answer :)

Comment: @meziantou You should really point out that it's *your* blog when posting things like that. Especially when you've already posted it an hour ago on the question.

Comment: I wrote on my blog [a step by step guide](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/04/25/publishing-an-asp-net-core-website-to-a-linux-host) to publish an ASP.NET Core website on Ubuntu